# IO Exception was unhandled. The process cannot access the file because it is being used

Tags: c#

I wrote a program, code seems working but it is not working. It gives IO exception was unhandled error. Some guys say me , you should delete something because program try to use same file at the same time. Please help me!!

```
      namespace App1508
     {
       public partial class Form2 : Form
      { 

      string goodDir = "C:\\GOOD\\";
      string badDir = "C:\\BAD\\";
      string fromDir = "C:\\DENEME\\";
      List<Image> images = null;
      int index = -1;
      FileInfo[] finfos = null;

       public Form2()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\DENEME");
          finfos = di.GetFiles("*.jpg",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
          images = new List<Image>();
          foreach (FileInfo fi in finfos)
         {
             images.Add(Image.FromFile(fi.FullName));

         }

       }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

         finfos[index].MoveTo(Path.Combine("C:\\GOOD", finfos[index].Name));

       }

         private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        index++;
        if (index < 0 || index >= images.Count)
        index = 0;
        pictureBox1.Image = images[index];

        }

         private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           finfos[index].MoveTo(Path.Combine("C:\\BAD", finfos[index].Name));

         }
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in finfos)
{
    images.Add(Image.FromFile(fi.FullName));
}
```

`Image.FromFile` will open a file handle, and won't close it until you dispose of the image. You're trying to move the file *without* disposing of the image which has that file open first.

I suspect if you dispose of the relevant image in your `button1_Click` and `button2_Click` methods (being aware that if it's showing in the `PictureBox` you'll need to remove it from there first) you'll find it works.

Ref:
http://support.microsoft.com/?id=814675

Comment: I don't understand it , please explain it with a code example.

Comment: @AytaçMacit: Which part do you not understand? You need to call `Dispose` on an `Image` before you can move the file which that `Image` is reading from. It's hard to give a clear sample as we don't know the structure of your application.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for helping to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet to the rescue :)